# variable date filter on large table too slow

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a huge table with 25 million records, and a system that has a scheduled task that can execute a query. The query needs to quickly pick up latest records by create date(timestamp) column and apply some calculations. The problem with this is that the date is also kept in a table and with each execution it is updated to the latest execution date. It does work but it is very slow:

```
select * from request_history
where createdate > (select startdate from request_history_config)
limit 10;
```

it takes about 20 seconds to complete, which is rediculously slow compared to this:

```
set custom.startDate = '2019-06-13T18:02:04';
select * from request_history
where createdate > current_setting('custom.startDate')::timestamp
limit 10;
```

and this query finishes well within 100 miliseconds. The problem with this is that I can't update and save the date for the next execution! I was looking for `SET` variable `TO` statement that would allow me to grab some value from a table but all these attempts are not working:

```
select set_config('custom.startDate', startDate, false) from request_history_config;
// ERROR:  function set_config(unknown, timestamp without time zone, boolean) does not exist

set custom.startDate to (select startDate from request_history_config);
// ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
```

Comment: How about splitting it into two statements: one that queries `request_history_config`, and one that uses the result from the first one?

Comment: Is the query actually taking a long time to execute or are you waiting for a lock to release on request_history_config?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_request_history()
 RETURNS TABLE(createdate timestamp)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
  start_date timestamp;
BEGIN
   SELECT startdate INTO start_date FROM request_history_config;
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT *
   FROM   request_history h
   WHERE  h.createdate > start_date
   LIMIT 10;
END
$function$
```

And then use the function to get values:

```
select * from get_request_history()
```